# Entity Framework Core Identity only getting currently logged in user when trying to access their comments

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, identity

My comments which are accessed on the announcement details page have a related user, however I can only display this data when logged in as that user. Can anyone help? Relevant code below

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User MyUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Announcement MyAnnouncement { get; set; }
    [Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(300)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    //public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Notice User(which inherits from ApplicationUser) MyUser is there and this data is correctly added to the database.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Comments)
{
    <div id="announcements">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyUser.FirstName) 
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyUser.LastName) <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
        <br />
    </div>
}
```

Is the relevant HTML code where the model is:

```
public class AnnouncementDetailsViewModel
{
    public Announcement Announcement { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

above is the viewmodel

```
User user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result;
comment.MyUser = user;
comment.MyAnnouncement = announcement;
_context.Comments.Add(comment);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Above is where the data is added in the controller which successfully adds to the database

I have no problem with any data excepting comment.MyUser.(any data) which only displays when that specific user is signed in and posts a comment

EDIT: get request in controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    Announcement announcement = await _context.Announcements
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
    if (announcement == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    AnnouncementDetailsViewModel vm = await GetAnnouncementDetailsViewModelByAnnouncement(announcement);

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually gets the data then?

Comment: @DavidG The HTML gets passed the viewmodel shown and is accessed using the HTML code shown above. I can edit the OP to show the get request in the controller if this would be helpful

Comment: I would say it's useful, everything above aleady looks OK

Comment: @DavidG I have edited the post

Comment: It looks like you're not loading the related data. Can you try `... _context.Announcements.Include(a => a.Comments.Select(c => c.MyUser)...`

Comment: @DavidG I cannot do this as  Announcements does not have Comments, there are referenced in the viewmodel not in the Announcements model.

Comment: So show where you get the comments! Come on buddy, don't drip feed the info, show us where the problem is.